Ubuntu problems with integrated graphics card in laptop with i5 13420H
I got a new laptop hp omen with i5 13420h.
I tried to install ubuntu. But there are some problems with it.
In 24.04 and 22.04 my mouse is freezing (it moves but the result of moving is shown only after change in direction of moving, it jumps)
In 24.10 screen is black though i hear sounds of the system.
Why I highlighted the processor model? When I choose discrete mode of graphics in bios and use only my Nvidia 4050 everything works fine.
I tried to update drivers using guide from here https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/client/overview.html
I tried to update firmware.
What can be the problem?

With nomodeset everything is okay as well. But I can not increase brightness, because no driver is used
